# program to write data to django DB has with throws error about settings.

Tags: python, django

i have a python program that reads in NMEA sentences and writes them to my django database.

```
update = breadCrumbs2(deviceID= device[0], time = tdStamp , latitude = msg.latitude,
                              longitude = msg.longitude , fixQualty = int(msg.gps_qual), 
                              numSat = int(msg.num_sats),hdop = msg.horizontal_dil, 
                              altitude = msg.altitude, geoIdalSeparation = msg.geo_sep,
                              deltaLastUpdate = Decimal(0), diffRefStationID = int(1), 
                              nmeaCheckSum = "")
        update.save()
```

this works fine when run from eclipse. but when i try to run it from my linux box i get an error:

"django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DATABASES, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings."

but when i go into the django shell to configure settings i get.

```
 >>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.configure()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 93, in configure
    raise RuntimeError('Settings already configured.')
RuntimeError: Settings already configured.
```

how to i correct this conflict. (i have restarted Django and Apache)

Comment: Can you specify the value of env variables DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE and PYTHON_PATH? You can print them in the angel you use to run your app

Comment: i am sorry i do not understand your comment. are you saying i need to spusifcly define my python and django settings in my program?   ['/usr/local/www/foo/bar/Breadcrumbs', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.4-py2.7.egg', '/usr/lib/python2.7', '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0', '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7']

Comment: And how would i print them in the "angel" (terminal?) i use used to run the app? i believe the above list is my python path. (displayed as part of an error message)